# c++ how to process the argu which uncertain type?

Tags: c++, json

There's a web api which output json format:

```
{"ret":0}
```

c++ program could get the value of "ret", and it's a INT type.

but if modify the api, output to this:

```
{"ret":"0"}
```

c++ program runs error.

what if the value of "ret" is uncertain type, maybe INT or maybe STRING?
is there a way to process the uncertain type value in c++?

Comment: Since C++ has no standard way of parsing JSON, I assume you're using an API. What is it?

Comment: Take a look at [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/any.html)

Comment: c++ code uses a third party library supplied by "json.org" to parse JSON

Comment: json.org doesn't supply any lib, it just lists what's available. _What API are you using?_.

Answer (score 0):

No, C++ is a [statically-typed language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing). It's my opinion that you should code against the datatypes of the API which should not change. It is commonly accepted that if the [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) chagnges, then the code calling that API has to change as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use Regex for different cases.

Like checking if there are two " around your input

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think Regex is a good way, I mean is there a uncertain type variable in C++, like "object" in C# or JAVA